# Too many connectivity problems in socket in react native with nestjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sockets, nestjs

i am using `nestjs`, `react-native` and `socket.io`

The socket version of `nestjs` is  `"socket.io": "^2.4.1"`.
`react-native` using version  `"socket.io-client": "^2.4.0",`.

The problem is that, presumably, there are too many connections to socket servers (`nestjs`) each time a component is rendered after it is mounted in `react-native`.
This problem connection is helps to slow down the speed of the server...

This is what the server logs look like.

[image]

I've tried many things to solve this problem, but I haven't solved it yet.

`react-native` It's a code that helps me connect.

```
 const socket = useRef<SocketIOClient.Socket>(io(`${httpUrl}`, { transports :  ['websocket'], query  : { device : Platform.OS }}));
    useEffect(()=>{
        socket.current?.connect()
    },[])
```

`nest.js` It's a code that helps me connect.

```
@WebSocketGateway( { transports: ['websocket','polling'] })
export class ChatGateWay implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect, OnGatewayInit {
    public handleConnection(client: Socket) {
          const query = this.getClientQuery(client);

          const remoteAddress = client.conn.remoteAddress

          if(!query.device){

              client.disconnect(true)

              ChatGateway.logger.debug(` DISCONNECTED === ${query.device} and ${remoteAddress} is connected!`);
            } else {

              ChatGateway.logger.debug(`${query.device} and ${remoteAddress} is 
              connected!`);

            }
      return true;
    }


}
```

Do you have a solution to address these issues?

Comment: This answer might provide solution / ideas to your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/67201479/12660598

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by configuring the class component as a provider and then adding the components that use the socket to it.

soveld code this,

```
class example extends Components {
   ...
   componentDidMount(){
      socket.connected()
   }
   componentWillUnmount(){
      socket.disconnected()  
   }
   render(){
      return <Chidren socket={socekt}/>
   }
}
```